# Using the Mutator Method in client program

Tags: java, eclipse, class, client, mutators

I just need some clarification whenever i use the Mutator Method in the client program okay so i my employee class set up and i was taught that my variable should be `private double salary` 
then have my Accessors then the Mutators and it should be `public void setSalary (double newSalary)` and inside it have `salary = newSalary`

Now, i'm coding this in eclipse and i'm in my client program so i put `Employee.setSalary(200.00);` which i was taught was the right way and the book we use in class also shows it like this...

However, Eclipse tells me that my mutator should be `public static void setSalary (double newSalary);` and that my initial variable should be `private static double salary`. why is it saying that if the book and my professor say it's the other way?

So here is my code for my class

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class Employee {
    private String Last_Name;
    private String First_Name;
    private int Years_in_Company;
    private double Salary;
    private char Status;
    private String Section;

    public Employee(){
        Last_Name = "unknown";
        First_Name = "unkown";
        Years_in_Company = 0;
        Salary = 0.0;
        Status = '\u0000';
        Section = "unkown";
    }

    public String getLast_Name(){
        return Last_Name;
    }

    public String getFirst_Name(){
        return First_Name;
    }

    public int getYears_in_Company(){
        return Years_in_Company;
    }

    public double getSalary(){
        return Salary;
    }

    public char getStatus (){
        return Status;
    }

    public String getSection(){
        return Section;
    }

    public void setLast_Name(String newLast_Name) {
        Last_Name = newLast_Name;
    }
    public void setFirst_Name(String newFirst_Name){
        First_Name = newFirst_Name;
    }
    public void setYears_in_Company(int newYears_in_Company){
        if( newYears_in_Company >= 0)
            Years_in_Company = newYears_in_Company;
            else{
                System.err.println ("Years in company cannot be negative");
                System.err.println ("Value not changed");
            }
    }
    public void setSalary (double newSalary){
        if ( newSalary >= 2000.00){ //good practice to add braces to `if`condition.
            Salary = newSalary;
              }
        else{
            System.err.println("Salary cannot be less than $2,000.00");
            System.err.println("Value not changed");
        }
    }
    public void setStatus(char newStatus){
        if (newStatus == 'a' || newStatus == 'r'){
            Status = newStatus;
                }
        else{
            System.err.println ("Status cannot be anything other than a or r");
            System.err.println ("Value not changed");
        }
    }
    public void setSection (String newSection){
        Section = newSection;
    }
    public void display (){
        System.out.println ( Last_Name + First_Name + Years_in_Company + Salary + Status + Section);
    }
    public String toString (){
        DecimalFormat SalaryFormat = new DecimalFormat ("#0.0");
        return "Name: " + Last_Name
                + ", " + First_Name
                + ", Years in Company: " + Years_in_Company
                + ", Salary: " + SalaryFormat.format ( Salary )
                + ", Status: " + Status
                + ", Section: " + Section;

    }
    public boolean equals( Object o){
        if (!(o instanceof Employee) ){
            return false;
                }
        else{
            Employee objEmployee = (Employee) o;
            if ( Last_Name.equals (objEmployee.Last_Name) &&
                    First_Name.equals (objEmployee.First_Name) &&
                    Math.abs(Years_in_Company - objEmployee.Years_in_Company) < 0.0001 &&
                    Math.abs(Salary - objEmployee.Salary) < 0.0001 &&
                    Status == objEmployee.Status &&
                    Section.equals(objEmployee.Section))

                    return true;
            else
                    return false;
        }
    }

}
```

i just want to know why Eclipse tells me that my mutator should be `public static void setSalary (double newSalary);` and that my initial variable should be `private static double salary`. why is it saying that if the book and my professor say it's the other way?

Comment: Can you show more codes?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i can put my codes on here if you want

Comment: Yes, you should, and please.

Comment: fyi, you should follow the java naming convention :)